# Errors updating 11.10

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, 11.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

These update errors are preventing upgrade Ubuntu 11.04. (I want to ultimately upgrade to 12.04):

```
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404 Not Found
http://extras/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404 Not Found
http://extras/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found
```

I check for updates pretty often but recently these have cropped up.  I'm learning as I go but need some assistance to resolve this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that extras not available in extras.ubuntu.com you need to disable the request by editing source list use following command

sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

add # in following urls Eg.
"#http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources"
"#http://extras/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-amd64/Packages"
"#http://extras/ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages"

and try updating.

or upgrade distro

Comment: Got it! Did it! Even upgraded to 12.04! Now I'm back to resolving the complete lack of audio output like my last upgrade...  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This is because Natty Narwhal has expired(End of Life) and its your chance to upgrade to higher version. [reference](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)